# What's the best way to consume an AngularJS service within a custom Kendo widget?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I have a custom Kendo widget like so:

```
var customWidget = widget.extend({
    options: {
        name: "MyCustomWidget"
    },

    init: function (element, options) {
        that = this;
        widget.fn.init.call(that, element, options);
    }
});
kendo.ui.plugin(customWidget);
```

Let's suppose that I also have a custom angularjs service that is providing some reusable utility function:

```
(function (ng) {
    ng.module('myApp').factory('myService', [], function () {
        var myRoutine = function(input) {
            return input * 5;
        };

        return {
            myRoutine: myRoutine
        };
    }]);
})(window.angular);
```

From somewhere within the widget, let's say for the sake of example the `init` function, I would like to use my angularjs service to call that utility function.

I haven't been able to find a spot in the lifecycle where the kendo widget can be defined early enough to then be used declaratively in my markup, but that is also within some kind of context that allows me to use static dependencies from my angularjs implementation.

What is the best way to accomplish this?  Do I have any options for statically injecting my angularjs service into the widget implementation as-is, or must I wrap the widget implementation within an angularjs directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never created a Kendo widget in the context of an Angular SPA, but the first option that comes to mind is to wrap the creation of your widget in a `.run()` block. That way, you're guaranteed your widget will be created at the appropriate time during execution of the dependency tree, but still before directives or templates (that might require the widget) are evaluated.

You can inject dependencies into `run()` blocks just like other Angular components. For example:

```
(function (ng) {

    ng.module('myApp').factory('myService', [], function () {
        var myRoutine = function(input) {
            return input * 5;
        };

        return {
            myRoutine: myRoutine
        };
    }]);

    ng.module('myApp').run(["myService", function (myService) {
        kendo.ui.plugin(widget.extend({
            options: {
                name: "MyCustomWidget"
            },

            init: function (element, options) {
                that = this;
                widget.fn.init.call(that, element, options);
                console.log(myService.myRoutine(10));
            }
        }));
    }]);

})(window.angular);
```